# AWS Lambda C# - Fail to query SQL with Dapper

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I've created a aws function, that works perfectly in local mode, but when executed in aws lambda, i got:

**Process exited before completing request**

The function uses Dapper to connect to a RDS SQL connection. I've checked the secutiry group and the inbound/outbound rules is right.

```
LambdaLogger.Log($"Listando doacao em visita");

        using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log($"Conexao aberta");

            var weekDay = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
            var stringSql = $@"{_query}
                    WHERE
                    p.status = {(int)StatusPedido.DoacaoEmVisita} and
                    p.datainclusao <= Getdate() - 7
                ";

            LambdaLogger.Log($"Query gerada");


            //the function exited on this line
            var query = conexao.Query<AlertaDisponibilidadeERetiradaDTO, EnderecoDTO, AlertaDisponibilidadeERetiradaDTO>(
                stringSql
                , (pedido, endereco) =>
                {
                    pedido.Endereco = endereco;
                    return pedido;
                }, splitOn: "IdEndereco");

            LambdaLogger.Log($"Query executada.");

            return query;
        }
```

I've wrapped the code with try/catch, to log why the exception occurs, but unfortunely the function exist instantly and i can't to know why.

Answer (score 0):

> Process exited before completing request

Indicates Exception with your Lambda. Check AWS Cloudwatch for the exception that is handled and logged to the cloudwatch.

If you don't see any logging, your dependency could be failing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: CloudWatch just logged the "LambdaLoger.Log", i wrapped the code with a try catch, but it isn't catched. I don't have any log to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by downgrading all packages dependings on .NET Standars 1.6.1 => 1.6.0